# Customizing Octave

Tags: terminal, octave

I am just starting with Octave and running it on my terminal so far.

Everytime I open the prompt, my command line starts with :

```
octave-3.4.0:1>
```

So I use the following to make it shorter and easier to read:

```
PS1('>> ')
```

How can I change my settings to exectute this code automatically everytime I open octave?

How top of this, is there a way to change my terminal settings to open Octave when I enter 'Octave'? The way I do it now is by using

```
'exec 'path/to/octave/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You can create edit `~/.octaverc` file that contains all the commands you want to execute when Octave starts up. This file is exactly like a `.m` Octave script file.

Just add `PS1('>> ')` to your `~/.octaverc` file. You can use your favorite text editor or use `echo` on the command line:

```
$ echo "PS1('>> ')" >> ~/.octaverc
```

After that you can see the `~/.octaverc` file :

```
$ more ~/.octaverc
```

It should contain the following line :

```
PS1('>> ')
```

For the second question, I am not sure if you're on OSX or Ubuntu or something else. If `octave` is in your search-path then you should be able to start Octave by just trying `octave`. Try these commands to find out what `octave` points to

```
$ which octave
/usr/bin/octave

$ type octave
octave is /usr/bin/octave
```

If somehow, `octave` is not your **`PATH`** search-path, this could be because you installed Octave at a non-standard location. You can do one of two things:

1. Add the folder containing your Octave executable to your **`PATH`** search-path. In `bash`, you can do this by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.profile` on MacOSX):

   ```
     export PATH=~/path/to/octave/folder:${PATH}
   ```
2. You can create a soft symlink to your octave executable.

   ```
   ln -s /path/to/octave/executable octave
   ```

This will create a symlink in your current folder. Now, as long as you're in the current folder, you'll be able to type in `octave` and run Octave. If you want to be able to run Octave from anywhere (and not necessarily the current folder), you need to add the current folder to your search-path (see point 1 above).

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the latest release which is [GNU Octave 3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/). It comes with a nice GUI if you're familiar with MATLAB.

You can customize the PS1 and any other settings on your `~/.octaverc`. Please read the documentation on startup files: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Startup-Files.html

As for calling Octave from anywhere, you need to set the `PATH` variable in your shell to append the directory where Octave is installed, for instace in Bash:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/octave-3.8/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Start GNU Octave with option `--traditional` (*but I'm not sure if this was already implemented in 3.4.x*).

```
$ octave --traditional
GNU Octave, version 3.8.1
Copyright (C) 2014 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".

Additional information about Octave is available at http://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit http://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read http://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

>> version
ans = 3.8.1
>>
```